# Как запускать concat и uglify в gulp.js при добавлении нового скрипта в таск gulpfile.js

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify, gulp-concat

Нужно чтоб при изменении в gulpfile.js (а именно при добавлении нового файла скрипта), запускался таск где заново какатенируются и ужимаются файлы в 1.
Пробовал смотреть за изменением gulpfile но почему-то не помогло

```
gulp.watch('gulpfile.js',['scripts'] );
```

Вот сам код gulpfile.js

```
var gulp   = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglifyjs');

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src([
        'app/js/libs/plugin.js',
        'app/js/common.js'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});


gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('gulpfile.js',['scripts'] );
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js',['scripts'] );
});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 0):

И не поможет, вы предлагаете галпу следить за самим собой. Нужно чтоб кто-то другой, который бы перезапускал бы галп.
Используйте [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon), запускайте его, чтоб он запускал gulp и чтоб он следил за gulpfile.js

```
nodemon -w gulpfile.js gulp
```

Comment: Буду пробовать, просто в grunt я следил за изменениями самого gruntfile и там если добавлять новые js файлы то он перекомпиливал js, думал и тут так сделать.